# How to open an image from adb in Gallery without touch panel?

Tags: android, adb

I have an image `/tmp/cute.jpg` which I want to show on my android I tried:

```
adb shell am start -t image/* file://tmp/cute.jpg
```

But it asks me to choose application (gallery or browser) to open with the image. 
I don't have touch, How can I enforce it to open the image with the gallery application ?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
adb shell am start  -t image/* file://tmp/cute.jpg -n com.android.gallery/com.android.camera.ViewImage
```

If this doesn't work, you might have to change the ComponentName to the one of the gallery installed on your phone.

In your case, you might have to push the file to the sdcard first:

```
adb push /tmp/cute.jpg /sdcard
```

...then open it:

```
adb shell am start  -t image/* /sdcard/cute.jpg -n com.android.gallery/com.android.camera.ViewImage
```

The path of your sdcard varies from device to device / Android version to Android version.

Comment: how can I list all the component on my device?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. You can find out the ComponentName by opening the app and looking at LogCat ("starting activity XYZ")

Comment: I think the image need to be in a specific directory... not /tmp

Comment: See my updated answer. I guess you have to push the file to your sdcard first, then open it from there.

Comment: I tried to push and open it from sdcard, though without `-n com.android.gallery/com.android.camera.ViewImage` and It opened the gallary and said there is 0 videos/images.